# Create a Map scale for Geodesic circles

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, coordinate-system, esri-geodatabase, basemap, arcgis-online-basemaps

I need some guidance.  I'm using an ESRI Base Map with Web Mercator projection(Wkid - 102110) in an web application using JavaScript. I'm drawing geodesic circles on the Base Map for a given radius and location and getting Map Scale using the ESRI getScale method.

The whole process works fine when im using an address in Florida.
[image]

But when i enter an address in Alaska, although the geodesic circle is correct, the scale is completely wrong.

[image]

I read a lot of online posts and everyone talks about how to create the geodesic circles which i already had working but not the scale. According to the scale generated by ESRI for the Alaska circle, the distance between the center of the circle and an end point is 19 miles although i intend to draw a circle of only 10 miles radius.

Also interesting to note that the scale on the bottom left of the base map seems to be correct but the one on on the print template is not.
How do i fix this?